# Best way to extract the data from the string

Tags: php, regex

I want to parse the mobile number from the string. The string may have a landline and extension code and a mobile number. The mobile number always starts with "Mobile:"

For example:

`Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx ext. 215 => return Empty`

`Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx Mobile: 9xx-xxx-x000 => return 9xx-xxx-x000`

`Mobile: 9xx-xxx-x000 Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx => return 9xx-xxx-x000`

`Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx Mobile: 9xx-xxx-x000 ext. 215 => return 9xx-xxx-x000`

`Mobile: 9xx-xxx-x000 Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx ext. 215 => return 9xx-xxx-x000`

`Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx ext. 215 Mobile: 9xx-xxx-x000 => return 9xx-xxx-x000`

I have tried following code to extract the mobile number but it's not working correctly -

```
$stringList = [
            "a" => "Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx ext. 215",
            "b" => "Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx Mobile: 9xx-xxx-x000",
            "c" => "Mobile: 9xx-xxx-x000 Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx",
            "d" => "Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx Mobile: 9xx-xxx-x000 ext. 215",
            "e" => "Mobile: 9xx-xxx-x000 Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx ext. 215",
            "f" => "Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx ext. 215 Mobile: 9xx-xxx-x000"
        ];

        $stringOutput = [];
        foreach($stringList as $k => $s) {
            if(strpos($s, "Mobile:") !== false) {
                $parseString = substr($s, strpos($s, "Mobile:"));
                $parseString = explode("Phone:", $parseString)[0];
                $parseString = explode("ext.", $parseString)[0];
                $stringOutput[$k] = trim($parseString);
            }
        }


# OUTPUT
Array
(
    [b] => Mobile: 9xx-xxx-x000
    [c] => Mobile: 9xx-xxx-x000
    [d] => Mobile: 9xx-xxx-x000
    [e] => Mobile: 9xx-xxx-x000
    [f] => Mobile: 9xx-xxx-x000
)
```

Is there any efficient way to achieve this task, are we able to parse this using regex or any other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a pattern with a capture group and a backreference to match the delimiters in the number.

```
\bMobile:\s*(\d{3}([ -]?)\d{3}\2\d{4})\b
```

- `\bMobile:\s*` Match the word `Mobile:` and optional whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d{3}` Match 3 digits
  - `([ -]?)` Capture **group 2** match a delimiter being an optional   or `-`
  - `\d{3}` Match 3 digits
  - `\2` Backreference to match the same as the captured delimiter in group 2
  - `\d{4}` Match 4 digits
- `)` Close group 1
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent an empty match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HwzMgP/1)

```
$s = "Mobile: 911-111-1000 Phone: 111-111-1111";
$pattern = '/\bMobile:\s*(\d{3}([ -]?)\d{3}\2\d{4})\b/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $s, $match)) {
    echo $match[1];
}
```

Output

```
911-111-1000
```

---

Or using `\K` without the outer capture group:

```
\bMobile:\s*\K\d{3}([ -]?)\d{3}\1\d{4}\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/006WPs/1)

```
$s = "Mobile: 9111111000 Phone: 111-111-1111";
$pattern = '/\bMobile:\s*\K\d{3}([ -]?)\d{3}\1\d{4}\b/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $s, $match)) {
    echo $match[0];
}
```

Output:

```
9111111000
```

Comment: Thank for answer. The first version of regex looks good `\bMobile:\s*(\d+(?:\d+){2}\b)`. Can we remove the dependency of hyphen as there maybe a change to get the format like this - `Mobile: (xxx) xxx xxxx` or `Mobile: xxxxxxxxxx`. Please suggest.

Comment: @IshanJain You can use a pattern with a backreference to keep the delimiters of the number the same `\bMobile:\s*(\d{3}([ -]?)\d{3}\2\d{4})\b` https://regex101.com/r/HwzMgP/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:
`Mobile:\s([^A-Za-z\n]+)\b`

```php
$re = '/Mobile:\s([^A-Za-z\n]+)\b/';
if (preg_match($re, $string, $match)) {
    echo trim($match[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All good answers, but in this case I would use preg_replace:

```
$pats = ['/.*mobile:/Ui', '/[a-z].*/i', '/[^0-9]/'];
$mobile = preg_replace($pats, '', $listing);
```

The first pattern gets rid of anything up to and including the "mobile:" tag.  The second pattern gets rid of anything after and including an alphabetic character (leaving you with just the mobile number), and the third pattern gets rid of non digits.  So you are left with all the numeric digits in the mobile number and nothing else.